# Network Bridge two interface with different subnet

Tags: networking, windows-xp, lan, bridge

I have two network lan card . each network interface connected with different subnet , each network interface has own wan connection . for example

Network interface 1 configuration

```
ip : 192.168.10.188
netmask : 255.255.255.0
gateway : 192.168.10.1
```

Network interface 2 configuration

```
ip : 192.168.1.14
netmask : 255.255.255.0
gateway : 192.168.1.1
```

When i select both network interface and do bridge i don't get any internet connection at all

How can i make bridge for the two network and get internet connection ?

Note : the reason i want to make bridge connection is to double my internet speed by combine both internet interfaces

Answer (score 0):

Enable ICS (Internet connection sharing) on those interface and you will have the Internet even after bridging.

How to configure [ICS](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/using-internet-connection-sharing#1TC=windows-7)

Comment: if i am not the only one on both network and if i enable ICS on Network interface 2 , any computer in Network interface 1 will be able to connect to network interface 2 through my computer right ?

Comment: the reason i want to make bridge is to double speed of my connection i add this in question as note

Comment: Double speed will not work, because from your computer you will initiate 1 session and this will not be treated as single session on 2 WAN. This is more bandwidth not a speed.

Comment: You need to look at going down the road of a DUAL WAN router with two Ethernet WAN ports to combine WAN's. This will not work.